# Why does my Wordpress website set a PHPSESSID cookie?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, session-cookies

I am currently struggling with the GDPR and all the changes it requires me to apply to my websites. One of my Wordpress websites, which uses a theme I made myself, sets a cookie named `PHPSESSID` which stores the session ID - not triggered by any particular action, just when any page of the website is opened.

The strange thing about it is:

1.) I definitely have nothing in my theme code that would do this.

2.) I have two identical versions of this website, one for testing on my own webspace and domain, the other on the clients domain and webspace. The provider is the same in both cases, so I suppose it's the same server configuration. The PHP version is the same (7.2). I have the same theme and plugins in both versions, still the performance site DOES set that cookie, the test site DOES NOT.

Now, all I actually want is to get rid of that cookie. I am not using any other cookies on that site and I don't want to have to put a cookie notice on that site.

Would anyone have an idea where that cookie could come from and how I could get the server/website to NOT set it?

Comment: WP doesn't set sessions out of the box, so this is either coming from a plugin or the server itself, which I'd be surprised if your host is setting a session automatically.

Comment: well, as I wrote: I have two versions of that website using the exact same theme and plugins, one sets it, one doesn't, which is what I am also puzzled about

Comment: If you open a new browser session (with previous cookies trashed), does the cookie get recreated? (Try a browser's incognito mode.)

Comment: Your cookie occurs on the production version, not the testing/development site?

Comment: @Progrock yes, the cookie is also set after trashing cookies and connecting in incognito mode, and also on other browsers. And yes, it occurs in the production version and not in the text version, although both domains/webspaces have the same hosting provider

Comment: The old: the two sites are exactly the same but different gotcha!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for session.
If you are using session by using session_start() at the most top of your script.
You can find this name (PHPSESSIONID) as an option value in your php.ini following part is from mine (php on IIS)

```
; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
; http://php.net/session.name
session.name = PHPSESSID
```

I suspect that (without having trying) that you have a cookie because there is an other option set

```
; Whether to use cookies.
; http://php.net/session.use-cookies
session.use_cookies = 1
```

you can read more about session and session cookies here http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-cookies

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering! I know about `session_start()`, but I don't use it anywhere (it's my own theme, nothing derived from templates or similar, kept rather simple). I'll have to check out the php.ini settings you mention, although I wouldn't be able to change them (it's on a shared webspace).

Comment: this directive is flaged as PHP_INI_ALL which means that you can set it with in_set function. Try ini_set ( "session.use_cookies", "0")  at the top most of the script, best before everything else. I don't know much about word press, but from somewhere you get that session, is it possible to be from the admin panel which requires login and should have session? what are the cookie values? check before you post something sensitive stored there

Comment: Hmm - I put `ini_set ( "session.use_cookies", "0");` at the top of my page, but I am getting a warning at the top of the page saying `Warning: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in /home/.sites/.../indexphp on line 2`. I am not logged into the Wordpress backend or into anything else on that website. The value of that cookie is an abstract sequence of characters, about 30 characters long. In the Firefox inspector, in the cookie information I also get `HostOnly: true"

Comment: Well i think that this has to do with WordPress somewhere something is included, don't see the script that you are working probably this is included in an other bigger script and all should start and end to an index.php or something similar page. But i cannot help you more i don't know about how wordpress is working, i could happily try to check some files but in order to provide you with a logical answer i should take a look at the whole project.....

Comment: Thanks for your offer! This is really at the top of the page (index.php, which includes header.php, footer.php and sidebar.php, but I inserted that line above everything else that the php file consists of). It seems that Wordpress connects to the server in a way that starts a session even befor the page itself is loaded. I just wonder why it doesn't happen at my test site as well, which is located at the same provider...

Comment: Could you have been hacked?  Check if you have any prepend script running:  `var_dump(ini_get('auto_prepend_file');`

Comment: Hi and thanks once more for your help, I really appreciate it! I found out that it was due to a plugin. I had two slightly different versions of that one plugin, one setting the PHPSESSID cookie (obviously before any php page is loaded), the other one not. Sorry, I should have checked that before (I found out by deactivating all plugins one by one).

Comment: Glad you find the solution. Since my answer was correct to the original question i will appreciate if you accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

To whoever is interested: I found out that it was due to a plugin. I had two slightly different versions/updates of that one plugin, one setting the PHPSESSID cookie (obviously before any php page is loaded), the other one not.

Sorry, I should have checked that before (I found out by deactivating all plugins one by one). But my problem is solved now - thanks to everybody who replied!

Comment: I don't suppose you remember which plugin?

Comment: @AuRise Sorry, no. This is more than 5 years old, I don't remember...

Comment: No worries, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For folks who might come across this, for me I'm pretty sure it was also a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/

But I don't think it was actually the plugin's fault, per se. Disabling it, then re-enabling it, THEN making sure it's settings enabled caching, seemed to "clear" the HTTP-only cookies. Basically I think the plugin was set up to work, but wasn't being used, so old HTTP-only images were being cached - even though I was consistently linking to HTTPS images. Anyway, just in case it might help.